# Rails jquery autocomplete field distorted

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, autocomplete

My app is based on [rails3-autocomplete-jquery](https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete)
Everything is woking great except it's distorting the related field. See the image below.

[image]

As you can see, the form field is distorted by the explanation automatically generated by the autocomplete gem. I want to know if I can customize or delete the entire explanation. Also, how do I position the explanation and the choices that come up?

Thank you for your help in advance. I appreciate it.

Comment: This most likely has to do with other markup on the page. Without the actual code there is not much anyone can do to figure out an answer to your question.

Answer (score 3):

you simply add following css to your code:

```
.ui-helper-hidden-accessible{ display:none}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input but it doesn't answer all my questions.

Comment: I'm facing this issue since new jQuery UI 1.9 is released. I did not find any documentation about how to customize or modify message.
then I decide to hide it because its destroyed my application layout.

Comment: adding the line doesn't get rid of the message though

Answer (score 0):

Are you using jQuery UI? As far as I know that gives it some basic styles so it appears over your other content. You could style it yourself by writing your own CSS to override the defaults. I'm not sure about changing the content of the messages though. You could either change the source or there might be something in the API http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Answer (score 0):

Without code, it's hard to give you anything other than generic web development advice.  This question isn't really answerable in its current form, but here are some comments on the issue:

- Try grepping your codebase and associated js files for "available, use up and down arrow". Any message which shows up on your page must be somewhere in the code used to generate it.  Work from there to see how where that message is defined and if it's possible to override it.  There is probably either a parameter you can feed to change the message, or you could just serve the javascript yourself and alter the message.
- As for positioning, you just need to update your CSS. Using Google Chrome, right-click and inspect element on the suggestions list, and you can see which CSS rules apply to it, and what the class names of various things are.  Find the stylesheets which define these rules and either edit them, or add additional rules to override them. In general, the webkit inspector in Chrome should be very helpful in diagnosing this what CSS rules are messing things up.

Finally, I have a few *guesses* about what might be causing this:

1. You might have some overly-broad CSS rules which are messing up the default positioning used by jquery-ui.
2. It might also be an incompatibility between the version of jquery or jquery-ui you are using and the associated stylesheets.  Try reinstalling the latest version of both, and the suggestions will probably look much nicer.
3. You might not be including the jquery-ui stylesheet at all.  Those suggestions look like they're not really styled or positioned at all, so there might just be a missing set of CSS directives.